# Using Javascript to get iframe code to open in new window

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have an html iframe code for a search box. What I want is to ensure that users can type a question into the search box on the original page but have the results open into a new tab. This is where I am having some trouble. I am trying to use javascript. What is the appropriate var window code that I should use that won't turn my results into a popup?

Comment: Java has nothing to do with JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

You do not need any javascript

```
<form target="_blank" method="get" action="https://www.google.com">
  <input type="text" name="q" />
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

If you want to use JavaScript, you need to use `window.open()`